# Amazon Athena -> HBase connection: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to glue.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:443

Tags: amazon-web-services, hbase, amazon-athena

could you please help me with the Amazon Athena to HBase connection.
I work with respect to the documentation while trying to setup data source. The connector successfully connects to the HBase instance on the Amazon EMR cluster, fetches table structure... Both columns and rows ids natively have strings as a values, but I can not prevent connector (or maybe Athena) to cast data types to some different ones: I have BIGINT or DOUBLE inside Athena table structure. Then I put to AWS Glue corresponding table structure: I have appropriate database and table inside, that equals to the names inside HBase.
But connector can't connect to AWS Glue with the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: 
Connect to glue.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:443 [glue.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/3.143.132.217, glue.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/18.188.134.211, glue.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/3.12.12.20, glue.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/3.23.23.240, glue.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/3.23.109.251, glue.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/3.129.154.43] failed: connect timed out
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1207) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1153) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlueClient.doInvoke(AWSGlueClient.java:8202) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlueClient.invoke(AWSGlueClient.java:8169) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlueClient.invoke(AWSGlueClient.java:8158) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlueClient.executeGetTable(AWSGlueClient.java:4774) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlueClient.getTable(AWSGlueClient.java:4745) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.athena.connector.lambda.handlers.GlueMetadataHandler.doGetTable(GlueMetadataHandler.java:347) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.athena.connectors.hbase.HbaseMetadataHandler.doGetTable(HbaseMetadataHandler.java:206) [task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.athena.connector.lambda.handlers.MetadataHandler.doHandleRequest(MetadataHandler.java:256) [task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.athena.connector.lambda.handlers.CompositeHandler.handleRequest(CompositeHandler.java:132) [task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.athena.connector.lambda.handlers.CompositeHandler.handleRequest(CompositeHandler.java:100) [task/:?]
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:902) [LambdaSandboxJava-1.0.jar:?]
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:340) [LambdaSandboxJava-1.0.jar:?]
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:63) [LambdaSandboxJava-1.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) [?:1.8.0_302]
    at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:150) [LambdaJavaRTEntry-1.0.jar:?]
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to glue.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:443 [glue.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/3.143.132.217, glue.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/18.188.134.211, glue.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/3.12.12.20, glue.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/3.23.23.240, glue.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/3.23.109.251, glue.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/3.129.154.43] failed: connect timed out
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151) ~[task/:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) ~[task/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy18.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[task/:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[task/:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[task/:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[task/:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[task/:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1330) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145) ~[task/:?]
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:368) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:142) ~[task/:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[task/:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) ~[task/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy18.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[task/:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[task/:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[task/:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[task/:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[task/:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1330) ~[task/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145) ~[task/:?]
```

Comment: Error says "connection timed out". Are you sure, connection is successful? If not, check VPC Access, connector needs privileges to attach/detach an interface to the VPC.  Also, while connecting to HBase, avoid connector inferring schema by supplying supplementary metadata. This helps in 95% datatype mismatch issues. Refer to https://github.com/awslabs/aws-athena-query-federation/tree/master/athena-hbase for more details.